# Can't get recreated range function to print a list in a negative step. It also prints an extra number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I've been instructed to make a function that has the same results as the range function without actually using the range function. I have it so it prints ascending lists but when I try to get it to print a descending list with a step of -1, it prints an empty list. I'm also getting an extra number at the end, check the test lines below.

```py
def myRange(start = 0, stop = 0, step = 1):
    number = start
    number_list = []
    if start == stop:
        return []
    while number <= stop:
        number_list.append(number)
        number = number + step
    return number_list
```

## These are the test lines for the function. All but the last one work.

```py
print(myRange(2,4, 6))
print(myRange(2,4, 1))
print(myRange(0,5,1))
print(myRange(4,1,-1))
```

## myRange(4,1,-1) prints an empty list instead of [4,3,2]

## This is the current output

```py
[2]
[2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[]
```

## This is the correct output

```py
[2]
[2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: It could be a bit unexpected question, but why don't use built-in `range()`?

Comment: Even ascending lists are not correct: `range(0, 10)` is `[0, ..., 9]`; `myRange(0, 10` is `[0, ..., 10]`. Remember that ranges do not include the endpoint (they are half-open).

Comment: `while number <= stop` is checking 4<=1 for your last test case which obviously doesn't enter the while loop.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I've been instructed to create my own function that mimicks range, but, I cannot use range.

Comment: @iz_ Yes, that is part of my issue. It's printing the endpoint as well.

Comment: @HenryYik If I change the code to `while number + step <= stop` it does fix the recording endpoints, however, the range test `print(myRange(2,4,6))` prints an empty list.

Comment: Hint: `while number <= stop:` should be `while number < stop:`. This should make a lot of sense if you've ever programmed in a language with a C-like `for` loop. Also, make sure to take into account cases where `number` starts off larger than `stop`. (This is causing your described issue with negative steps.)

Comment: @iz_ thanks man, that definitely solved the endpoint being included. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the negative steps, it's still recording as an empty list.

Comment: So, I made a discovery. If I change the while loop to `while number > stop`
it prints the descending list, however, it leaves the ascending ones empty. I tried making it `while number > stop or number < stop` but it breaks the entire program.

Comment: I don't want to do your homework for you, but make sure you think this through. If you want a descending list, your condition should be flipped around. You can solve this by using a `if` statement or even some Boolean logic in the `while` loop condition. I would prefer the latter. It should look something like `while number < stop or (step < 0 and number > stop):`. Make sure you understand how this works (a piece of paper and a pencil might help).

Comment: @iz_ I actually just got it to work by creating a second while loop with the condition reversed. I have a question though if you don't mind. When I put the while loop for `while number > stop:` under the reversed loop, the program crashes, but when I put it on top, it works fine, why is this?

Comment: If "the program crashes" means an infinite loop, it is because the condition never fails. If `while number > stop` is on the bottom, for ascending ranges, the first while loop will increment `number` until it is (in some cases) strictly greater than `stop`. In this case, the code under the second while loop will just keep incrementing `number`. Obviously, it started greater than `stop`, and it's getting bigger. The `while` loop will never exit. I wouldn't recommend two while loops and the duplicate code; it can make code hard to maintain. A more complex Boolean condition is what I would do.

Comment: @iz_ Something along the lines of ```while stop != start:``` then the conditions?

Comment: See my comment above (a few comments ago).

Answer (score 0):

use an **if** statement

```
def myRange(start = 0, stop = 0, step = 1):
    number = start
    number_list = []
    if step > 0 :
        while number <= stop:
            number_list.append(number)
            number = number + step
    elif step < 0:
        while number >= stop:
            number_list.append(number)
            number = number + step
    return number_list
```